# Erlang global and local names

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Why **local** names (registered using erlang:register/2) can only be atoms and not arbitrary term, but the **global** names could be anything (registered using global:register_name/2,3).

Type spec from gen.erl:

```
-type emgr_name()  :: {'local', atom()}
                    | {'global', term()}
                    | {'via', Module :: module(), Name :: term()}.
```

Why there is no way to give a **local** gen_server an arbitrary name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because local registration is feature of Erlang (written on C).
But global registration is feature of global module from OTP. it just extension of standard behaviour.